# Active Directory works via Users and Computers GUIs, but AD PS is not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Yesterday AD on my workstation was working fine. I could query AD from the Users and Computers GUI or from Powershell. An update was pushed last night and I came into work this morning and AD RSAT had been uninstalled (normal). I reinstalled it and the Users and Computers GUI works but all AD modules in PS fail with `WARNING: Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.`

Obviously I have some level of connectivity to the servers and the servers haven't been touched and still have AD installed, since the GUI is working fine. But I can't call any AD modules from Powershell.

Comment: Have you looked at the AD Web Services? It may have stopped. Try restarting that. Also look at things as windows firewall.

Comment: Oddly enough, one of our in-house GUI wrappers for Powershell AD Module works, and a second GUI wrapper doesn't work. I opened up the wrapper that works and looked through the PS1 file for it, only thing different is that this one imports AD and then specifies the cmdlets and the Domain. I tried trowing that into ISE and seeing if I could call a function, but still nothing.

Web service is running on all DCs. I don't think it's a firewall, not even sure if we have firewalls on these workstations...

Comment: I was of course talking about the firewalls on the DC's.

Comment: Yeah, that makes way more sense... Checking now

Comment: I figured out the issue. It was a really silly one actually. I can only access LDAP/AD through a VPN and the update uninstalled AnyConnect. I reinstalled and connected to my VPN and now everything is working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you solved it. :)